# Post to Facebook/Twitter using Django?

Tags: django

Maybe I've already found the answer on Google but I don't recognize it so I resort to you guys.

What packages do I need? A tutorial would be awesome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

A package such as [`django-socialregistration`](https://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration) would allow you to authenticate with both.

Alternatively, you could roll your own using one of these:

- [Facebook `python-sdk`](https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk)
- [`python-twitter`](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/)

Answer (score 1):

You want Twython:

https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython-django/blob/master/twython_django_oauth/views.py

Believe me, I have been down this road, and the example Django views in the link above are the most straightforward of twitter oauth2 examples.

See also https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython